# Plotting Specific Regions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to python. The problem is that, assume that we have two parameters, x and y, and four functions f_1, f_2, f_3 and f_4. Suppose that we know that:

1. If (x < 5 < y < 5+x) or (5 <= y < x) or (x= 5 and 5 < y < 10) then function f_1 is the maximum function.
2. If (5 < x < y < 5 + x) or (x <= y < 5) then function f_2 is the maximum function.
3. If (y < x < 5) or (y < 5 < x) or ( x = 5 and y < x) then function f_3 is the maximum function.
4. If y > x+5 then function f_4 is the maximum function.

I need to draw a plot with x-axis = x and y-axis = y which shows the regions under which each function is the maximum function.

I used the following code, however the resulted plot, shown below, is not accurate.

[image: Resulted Plot]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,10,.1)
y = np.arange(0,15,.2)
x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y) 
maxf = np.zeros(shape = x)
maxf.fill(-9999.99) 

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        if j<i<5 or j<5<i:
            maxf[i,j] =1
        elif i<5<=j<i+5 or 5<=j<i:
            maxf[i,j] =2
        elif 5<i<=j<i+5 or i<=j<5:
            maxf[i,j] =3
        elif i == 5 and j<5:
            maxf[i,j]=1
        elif i == 5 and 5<=j<10:
            maxf[i,j]=2
        elif j >= 5+i:
            maxf[i,j]=4


plt.contourf(x,y,maxf)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The result should have been sth like the following picture:

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What did you try?

Comment: @BenT That's actually the simplified version of the question that I asked you before and as I mentioned in that question when I used -9999.99 instead of np.nan the plot got totally strange. So, I just simplified the conditions under which each function is the maximum function to see if it makes it easier to draw the plot under these new conditions

Comment: So post the plot and the code you used to make it. We can't help if we don't see what you have...

Comment: You need `x.shape` when you create `maxf`

Comment: I just added your code to the main body of the question. However, as I mentioned since now I changed all the conditions whenever I ran the code I face an error related to the shape of maxf.

Comment: Thanks @BenT. I got rid of the error, however the resulted plot is not accurate. Please look at the picture I attached right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the initial array to -9999.99 you now have to make sure you only contour the values that you want which is between 1-3. Since that value is so much bigger in magnitude it does not get included in your plot. Set your contour levels for your plot using this:

```
plt.contourf(x,y,maxf,[0,1,2,3])
```

Yields:

[image]

**Update**

I didn't notice before but you are using `i,j` like they are the numbers but they actually represent the indexes of the arrays which is throwing off your calculation. You need to know the index and the value so you can use `enumerate`. If this is still not correct, then you need to revisit your logic in your conditions.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y = np.arange(0,15,.01)
x = np.arange(0,10,.01)

Y,X = np.meshgrid(y,x) 

maxf = np.zeros(shape = Y.shape)
maxf.fill(-9999.99) 


for i,x_ in enumerate(x):
    for j, y_ in enumerate(y):
        if y_<x_<5 or y_<5<x_:
            maxf[i,j] =3
        elif x_<5<=y_<(x_+5) or 5<=y_<x_:
            maxf[i,j] =1
        elif 5<x_<=y_<(x_+5) or x_<=y_<5:
            maxf[i,j] =2
        elif x_ == 5 and y_<5:
            maxf[i,j]=3
        elif x_ == 5 and y_>=5:
            maxf[i,j]=1
        elif y_ >= (5+x_):
            maxf[i,j]=4


plt.contourf(X,Y,maxf,[0,1,2,3,4])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Final Note**

Just because you add a condition does not mean it will get evaluated if another condition is met first. In this case your 4th function is never true because one of the other conditions is always met. If you want that condition first, then make it your first `if` statement. How you arrange your logical statements matters especially since you have lots of conditions and some of which overlap each other.

Comment: Dear @BenT, thanks for your great help. Unfortunately, again the plot is not accurate. I attached a picture which shows what the resulted plot should look like. I should say that I added another condition which also covers region where y > = x+5 . I assumed that if this happens then f_4 is the maximum function.

Comment: Edited my answer. Also for future reference you should consider upvoting the answer and not select it as the answer until you have solved your problem.

Comment: A quick question @Bent; I just double checked all the conditions and I found no overlap between them. It seems the plot is not accurate again. For instance, when x<=y<5 (i.e. second elif ) then maxf [i,j] = 3, however in the plot it shows 1. Do I need to change parameter in the code?

Comment: In fact, the plot should exactly be like the picture I put in the end of the main post.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPkRC.png

Comment: Edited my answer. You had your numbers wrong in which figure goes where.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete answer @BenT. It is a really great help to me.

Comment: Dear @BenT, do you have any idea how can I put the name of functions on their related region on the plot? I mean right now it is not clear that for example the purple color stands for which one of the functions.

Comment: Do you want to provide the names on the colorbar? Or do you want to remove the colorbar and just add text to the figure. There are lots of questions on how to add text to a figure just do a google search.

Comment: I just wanted to add text to the figure and I realized that it can be done by using "ax.text"